# Testing Serviceworker and React Components (ES6)

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, google-chrome-headless

I have written some react code and added a service worker for offline features. I would like to cover my code with unit and integration tests. Is there a way to test my react components and my service worker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Proxy Pattern.

1) Create class ServiceWorkerInterface

2) Create class ServiceWorkerMock (extends ServiceWorkerInterface)

3) Create class ServiceWorkerBrowser (extends ServiceWorkerInterface). It contains real ServiceWorker

Props:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  serviceWorker: PropTypes.instanceOf(ServiceWorkerInterface)
}
```

Methods:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
 /**
 * @return {ServiceWorkerInterface}
 */
  getServiceWorker () {
    return this.props.serviceWorker
  }
}
```